# JPA - Select when parameter is a member of attribute, attribute is a set of string

Tags: java, sql, spring-data-jpa

`NoticeGroupEntity`:

```
@Id
@Column(name = "id")
private long id;

@Column(name = "name")
private String name;

@Column(name = "allowed_user_statuses")
@Convert(converter = StringSetConverter.class)
private Set<String> allowedUserStatuses;
```

This is `StringSetConverter`

```
public class StringSetConverter implements AttributeConverter<Set<String>, String> {

@Override
public String convertToDatabaseColumn(Set<String> list) {
    return String.join(",", list);
}

@Override
public Set<String> convertToEntityAttribute(String joined) {
    return new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(joined.split(",")));
}
```

I try to select `NoticeGroupEntity` by using JPA:

```
@Query("SELECT ng FROM #{#entityName} ng WHERE ?1 IN ng.allowedUserStatuses")
List<NoticeGroupEntity> findByAllowedUserStatus(String userStatus);
```

Any way to select? It does not return any entity.
Thanks.

Comment: This is not working in this way. Your status set is only available in the entity layer, but your query will be tarnslated to native sql and run in the db layer.

Comment: You cant use a SpeL expression for the entity name: https://spring.io/blog/2014/07/15/spel-support-in-spring-data-jpa-query-definitions

Comment: @SándorJuhos Maybe you are right. I will research it. I have resolved this problem by using another way.

Answer (score 0):

Your `@Query` is so strange.

Try this:

```
@Query("SELECT ng FROM NoticeGroupEntity ng WHERE ?1 member ng.allowedUserStatuses")
```

The above work for entity. I haven't tried with primitive type yet.

In case it does not work, native query will come to rescue:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT ng FROM NoticeGroupEntity ng WHERE ng.allowed_user_statuses LIKE ?1", native = true)
```

And pass your parameter as `"%" + status + "%"`

Comment: I try your answer, but not working too, Thank you, Please note that ng.allowedUserStatuses is a set of String, and userStatus is just a String and maybe is a member of ng.allowedUserStatuses.

Comment: "member of" instead of "member".
It throw java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query

Comment: It does not work with primitive? You can try native query. Modify your query to match with normal SQL, it always work

Comment: Yes, sql with like %status% is new idea, but if ng.allowed_user_statuses contain: ACTIVE, INACTIVE it should be get all.

Comment: You have two option: Normalize your DB to split the `Status` instead of joining as a column OR create custom query which accept special value